# Dynamically create a point array

Tags: c#, point

I would like to draw a curve using `graphics.DrawCurve` and I have x and y values in separate arrays (`float x[]` and `float y[]`). As `DrawCurve` needs point array as input, I need to convert or dynamically create the point array from the float arrays x and y. Is there any quick way for this?

I have around 20000 points for plotting the curve, Is it good idea to use `graphics.DrawCurve` on this purpose?

Comment: The only way is to join the two arrays together, but then would you not be better off with a list of points to begin with? What have you tried?

Comment: I couldn't try anything so far except searching. What I try to apply is first allocate the point array and dynamically collect the x and y values in the allocated point array in a loop. But, so far I couldn't find out how to allocate a point array. (why is the minus vote for??)

Comment: Are you looking for [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698.aspx) (LINQ)? - As in (untested): `xArray.Zip(yArray, (x, y) => (new Point(x,y))).ToArray()`

Comment: Well what have you researched so far and what hasn't worked? Show what you have tried, the downvote is because you haven't shown any research/effort

Comment: Ah cool! So googling the problem and spending different coding combinations for half day is not counted as an effort. Next time I will handstanding while googling it to show I spend really an effort to solve my problem. Other issue is that it is not easy to separate array pointers and point array in the search results; though there are enough questions&answers for array pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several questions to answer.

> I couldn't find out how to allocate a point array.

Well, there is no difference in allocating a point array than to do so for any other kind of array:

```
const int size = 100;
Point[] pointArray = new Point[size];
```

But arrays are missing some "convenience". For example, they have a fixed size that you need to specify at the point of initialization (allocation). And if you need more space, you have to manually create a new (bigger) array and copy all the values from the old to the new.

That's why almost everywhere you would work with an array, you're probably better off using a list:

```
List<Point> pointList = new List<Point>();
```

And then, wherever you actually need to pass an array, you can simply get it via:

```
Point[] pointArray = pointList.ToArray();
```

> dynamically collect the x and y values in the allocated point array

When you work with a list, that's as easy as:

```
pointList.Add(new Point(x, y));
```

We don't know how you fill your `float x[]` and `float y[]`. If possible, I'd not have those two separate arrays in the first place and simply use the `pointList` from the start. With one caveat: a [System.Drawing.Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Drawing.Point.aspx) only works with `int` values, not with `float` values. So I assume you meant to collect `int` values for the coordinates.

> dynamically create the point array from the float arrays x and y

If you cannot change the collection of the coordinates and *have* to work with those arrays, you can "zip" them together like this:

```
IEnumerable<Point> points = x.Zip(y, (xCoord, yCoord) => 
    (new Point((int)xCoord, (int)yCoord));
```

Or, if you know you need an array:

```
Point[] pointArray = x.Zip(y, (xCoord, yCoord) => 
    (new Point((int)xCoord, (int)yCoord)).ToArray();
```

For this, you need to be able to use `System.Linq` (in other words higher than .Net 2.0).

If you cannot use Linq, you have to do it "by hand". Something like:

```
int size = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);
Point[] pointArray = new Point[size];

for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
  pointArray[index] = new Point((int)x[index], (int)y[index]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and discussion. I have indeed float numbers and I used following loop: `PointF[] pointArray = new PointF[500];
            for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
                pointArray[i] = new PointF((float)yPoints[i], (float)xPoints[i]);
            }`
However creating list and adding point to the list doesn't work with the Graphics.DrawCurve.
I have indeed float values in the x axis and actually it works well with the Graphics.DrawCurve. I haven’t tried the Linq solution so far and I will edit this response when I compare the runtime of the solutions.

Comment: Ah, okay, so change every `Point` in my answer to `PointF`, remove the `(int)` casting and forget what I wrote about needing `int` ^_^. I don't quite understand what you mean by "creating list and adding point to the list doesn't work with the Graphics.DrawCurve". Do you get an exception or a compile error? "doesn't work" could mean anything. -- are you missing any of the other parameters needed for [Graphics.DrawCurve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa327509.aspx)?

Comment: Unfortunately only 600 chars possible in the comments so I couldn't write in detail. When I use
'List<PointF> pointArray = new List<PointF>();
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
 pointArray.Add(new PointF((float)yPoints[i], (float)xPoints[i]));
 }
 g.DrawCurve(pen, pointArray, 1F);'
I got following error (Error 4 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.PointF>' to 'System.Drawing.PointF[]'

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by "And then, wherever you actually need to pass an array, you can simply get it via: `Point[] pointArray = pointList.ToArray();`" -- so in your case, you have to write: `g.DrawCurve(pen, pointArray.ToArray(), 1F);`

Answer (score 2):

You can create `List<Point>` which is better than arrays.

```
List<Point> list = new List<Point>();
Point point=new Point(10,15);
list.Add(point);
```

You can get all x and y coordinates from two arrays and put together in list as points and than use this list to draw curve.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: That answers the question actually. However the solution Corak has offered is more detailed and discuss the issue better. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Given the values in both arrays have the same Index you can itereate over them, create points and add them to a list.

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++){
    points.Add(new Point(x[i],y[i]);
}
```

I don't see a particular problem in using `DrawCurve` here.

If you need an array of Points use `points.ToArray();`